# Modify fancybox options (margins) after initializing a gallery

Tags: javascript, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox version 2.1.4 gallery of iframes that I open and then insert a right column in the parent body (outside the fb iframe) that display descriptions.  In order to size the iframe properly I pass in margin : [120, 340, 40, 40] in the options when initializing fancybox.  So far so good.  The right column is fixed, and fancybox resizes nicely in the space allotted to it.

However, now I would like users to be able to collapse the right column and have the fancybox iframe expand to the full page.  Getting the right column to collapse to 40px wide is easy.  However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the right margin of an open fancybox gallery from 340 to 60.  There's nothing in the api, and nothing in SO or google that I can find, and reading through the source code didn't help either. Hopefully there is something simple that I'm just missing, but I could use some help.

As a temporary fix I pass the current object to the right column loader and modify the margins directly, then check to see if the right column is collapsed in the afterload callback.  ugly but functional.  Surely there is a better way.  An api for $.fancybox.options({newKey: newValue}) would be nice.

Here's the option code and the function that loads the right column:

```
ssTabs.fancyboxOptions = {
        scrollOutside: true,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        arrows: false, 
        closeBtn: false, 
        //using live prevents multiple event handlers when adding content or switching views
        live: false,
        beforeLoad: function(){
            $('.notes_html').css('position', 'relative').css('top', '0').css('left', '0');
        },
         afterLoad: function(current, next) {
            var marginsOpen = [80, 340, 20, 20];
            var marginsCollapsed = [80, 60, 20, 20];
            var marginsPhone = [60, 0, 0, 0];
            var margins = marginsOpen;
            if ($('body').hasClass('fb_rc_collapsed')) {
                margins = marginsCollapsed;
            }
            if ($('body').hasClass('mobile')) {
                console.log('setting fb margins to mobile');
                margins = marginsPhone;
            }
            ssTabs.addFbMenuBar(current);
            console.log('current: ', current);
            if(current.type === "inline" || current.type === "iframe") {
                current.minHeight = "100%";
                current.minWidth = "100%";
            }
            if(current.type === "iframe") {
                this.margin = margins;
                //current.maxWidth = 1200;
            }
        },
        beforeClose: function(){
          $('.notes_html').css('position', 'absolute').css('top', '-9999px').css('left', '-9999px');  
        },
        afterClose: function(){
            ssTabs.removeFbMenuBar();
        },
        iframe: {
            preload: false
        },
        padding: 5,
        margin : [120, 340, 40, 40],
        mouseWheel: false,
        helpers:  {
            title: null,
            overlay : {
                closeClick : false
            }
        }
};

ssTabs.addFbMenuBar = function(current) {
    zim.currentFbElement = current;
    var thisElement = current.element[0].dataset;
    var options = {};
    options.mySphere = zim.mySphere || false;
    options.sphereOwner = zim.thisSphereOwner;
    var contentArray = {content: zim.objectDictionary[thisElement.id]};
    var context = $.extend({}, contentArray, options);
    console.log('fb context: ', context);
    var template = 'fb_overlay';
    var location = '#gallery_right_column';
    console.log('inserting fb_menu_bar'); 
    $(location).handlebars(template, context, {}, checkForMobile);
    function checkForMobile() {
        if ($('body').hasClass('mobile')) {
            $('.fb_rcolumn').hide();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: is the right column inserted from and inside the iframed page? or is it inserted on top of the iframe (from the parent page the opened fancybox) within the fancybox containers? ... I shouldn't be asking this, you should be showing your code instead.

Comment: Code posted.  I thought it was obvious, but i'm also too close to the problem.  I also included a functional, but ugly workaround.  I can't believe there isn't a direct way to modify the options for an open fb gallery, but perhaps that's the case.  It doesn't appear to be in the doc or code.